# Issues importing material-ui v1-beta in create-react-app program

Tags: material-ui, create-react-app

I have a [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) based application. The following import used to work with material-ui v0.19.0.

```
import  FlatButton  from 'material-ui/FlatButton';
```

When I upgraded to the "next" version (i.e. v1-beta), the import fails with:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'material-ui/FlatButton' in '..../src/components'
```

Any ideas, what may be causing this?

Answer (score 2):

The API has changed for v1, especially for [Button](https://material-ui-1dab0.firebaseapp.com/api/button/):

```
import Button from 'material-ui/Button';
```

The individual components that existed for flat, raised, and floating-action buttons have been merged into `Button`.  Flat is the default presentation.  Raised and floating-action presentations are specified via the `raised` and `fab` boolean properties, respectively (both default to false).

Take a look at the [component demo](https://material-ui-1dab0.firebaseapp.com/demos/buttons/) to get a feel for how the various buttons can be used and review the [API documentation](https://material-ui-1dab0.firebaseapp.com/api/button/).